# Is there an equivalent to MacRabbit's cssedit on Ubuntu?

Tags: emacs, editor, css

If there is an emacs pluggin that would give me similar functionality, that would be welcome as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

About the best I know of is `css-mode`:

```
Package: css-mode
Description: A Cascading Style Sheets (CSS) editing mode for Emacs
 This is a simple Emacs mode for editing CSS style sheets. It adds
 font-locking and some basic auto-indentation support to Emacs. It
 works with Emacs 19.34, but should also work with both older and
 newer versions as well as XEmacs.
 .
 While CSS has a C-like syntax, this mode does a better job than
 cc-mode of handling the features of the CSS language.  It supports
 both CSS Level 1 and Level 2.
Homepage: http://www.garshol.priv.no/download/software/css-mode/
```

Answer (score 3):

All “programming” text editors (**gedit**, **scite**, **jEdit**, …) support syntax highlighting and features like code folding. More advanced editors that have specific CSS/HTML features (e.g. a colour picker) in the Ubuntu repos:

- **cssed** : http://cssed.sourceforge.net/ (GTK application. development seems to have stopped, though)
- **Quanta Plus** (package name *quanta*): http://freecode.com/projects/quantaplus (Qt application, also not much development recently...)
- **Bluefish**: http://bluefish.openoffice.nl/ (GTK app, recently version 2.0 was released and is included in Ubuntu 10.10. Current Ubuntu still has 1.0.7)

Bluefish would be my recommendation.

Answer (score 2):

[geany](http://www.geany.org) with [snippets](http://www.geany.org/Download/Extras) may help but its not specific to css but in general a very lightweight text editor.